# how to do something when xcode restarts or interrupts the program

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to save some page data when xcode restarts or interrupts the program, but I do not see the application lifecycle function at this moment, what should I do？

Comment: that scenario is not part of the application-life cycle; why would you need to do anything at all at the first place when Xcode restarts your app in a dev-environment, btw? _(potential XY-problem...?)_

Comment: I want to keep track of the last displayed page when the program is rerun, but do not want to keep it all the time

Comment: step away of the dev-environment and go for a real-environment, immediately you can find many useful [notification / delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate) to deal with such situation based on the application _standard_ life-cycle – you won't need anything more beyond that to cover this.

Comment: I need this is for ease of development, just use in debug mode

Comment: do it manually – save the screenshot (in the simulator) or take a screenshot (on real device) then press the _build-and-run_ (▶) button in Xcode – if you need you can attach the saved screenshot to your project as well; as you said you need it only in a debug environment, that kinda covers your needs.

Comment: Take what you say save the screenshot as an example, which method to save it, this is my problem

Comment: from the simulator: just press ⌘S; from the real device: in Xcode just press ⇧⌘2 then _Devices_ and press _Take Screenshot_ – both procedures will save the screenshots to your Desktop, you can use them from there freely.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.   When Xcode terminates a program, it is a hard termination and there is nothing the program can do about it.

Instead, save the state on entry to the state.